# win32 perl IPC::Open3() polling fhandles

Tags: perl, winapi, nonblocking, polling, ipcopen3

I need a means to poll (ie: non-blocking-IO) on the handles created by the Win32 version of open3(), using the standard core perl items.

things I know that will not work:

- OPEN3 - on windows, does not return normal file handles
- select() on windows, only works on sockets
- IPC::Run() does not let me interact with the child process

Oh, I wish 'expect' was part of perl on windows - but it is not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Standard core Perl is a very wide definition, especially on Windows. What preicise version and what flavour of Perl (ActivePerl, Strawberry, ...) ware we talking about?

Comment: Your first claim is wrong. The second claim shows you know what to you instead of pipes if you want to use select on Windows, and the third claim is either incorrect or the reason Expect can't possibly run on Windows (depending on your definition of "interact").

Comment: Claim#2 - See perlport - select()

Comment: @user3696153, Was that addressed to me? (You need to including `@ikegami` for me to get notified.) I didn't say claim #2 was wrong. I said you already gave the solution to your own problem: Use sockets if you want to use select(). I'd use IPC::Run personally. Way simpler.